# Looking for an app/website for shadowing

Tags: resource-request, english, shadowing

I am a English learner. Recently I want to practice shadowing. So I'm looking for an app/a website  that offers daily tips in English(e.g. usage/phrases etc.)Ideally, the tips shall be read out by a real human if possible.
(I also posted in the English learners group but it said irrelevant:(  )
[Need help: App/Websites recommendation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/need-help-app-websites-recommendation)

Comment: Have you tried YouTube? Recently, I have wanted to practice x.

Comment: @Lambie Thx but I would like use the resource like scripts and audio (like podcast) not video lol.

Comment: If you're copying what a person says, it's best to see their face...